# loop over pandas column for wmd similarity

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, gensim, word2vec

I have two dataframe. both have two columns. I want to use wmd to find closest match for each entity in column `source_label` to entities in column `target_label` However, at the end I would like to have a DataFrame with all the 4 columns with respect to the entities.

#### df1

```
,source_Label,source_uri
'neuronal ceroid lipofuscinosis 8',"http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/DOID_0110723"
'autosomal dominant distal hereditary motor neuronopathy',"http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/DOID_0111198"
```

#### df2

```
,target_label,target_uri
'neuronal ceroid ',"http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/DOID_0110748"
'autosomal dominanthereditary',"http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/DOID_0111110"
```

#### Expected result

```
,source_label, target_label, source_uri, target_uri, wmd score
'neuronal ceroid lipofuscinosis 8', 'neuronal ceroid ', "http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/DOID_0110723", "http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/DOID_0110748", 0.98
'autosomal dominant distal hereditary motor neuronopathy', 'autosomal dominanthereditary', "http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/DOID_0111198", "http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/DOID_0111110", 0.65
```

The dataframe is so big that I am looking for some faster way to iterate over both label columns. So far I tried this:

```
list_distances = []
temp = []

def preprocess(sentence):
    return [w for w in sentence.lower().split()]

entity = df1['source_label']
target = df2['target_label']

 for i in tqdm(entity):
    for j in target:
        wmd_distance = model.wmdistance(preprocess(i), preprocess(j))
        temp.append(wmd_distance)
    list_distances.append(min(temp))
# print("list_distances", list_distances)
WMD_Dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'source_label': pd.Series(entity),
                              'target_label': pd.Series(target),
                              'source_uri': df1['source_uri'],
                              'target_uri': df2['target_uri'],
                              'wmd_Score': pd.Series(list_distances)}).sort_values(by=['wmd_Score'])
WMD_Dataframe = WMD_Dataframe.reset_index()
```

First of all this code is not working well as the other two columns are coming directly from the dfs' and do not take entities relation with the uri into consideration.
How one can make it faster as the entities are in millions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick fix :

```
closest_neighbour_index_df2 = []


def preprocess(sentence):
    return [w for w in sentence.lower().split()]



 
for i in tqdm(entity):
    temp = []
    for j in target:
        wmd_distance = model.wmdistance(preprocess(i), preprocess(j))
        temp.append(wmd_distance)
    # maybe assert to make sure its always right
    closest_neighbour_index_df2.append(np.argmin(np.array(temp))) 
    # return argmin to return index rather than the value. 
    
# Add the indices from df2 to df1

df1['closest_neighbour'] = closest_neighbour_index_df2 
# add information to respective row from df2 using the closest_neighbour column
```